# Is it possible to manipulate a graphics object with 3 rotation transforms simultaneously?

Tags: graphics3d, geometric-transform

The code that I have written has an unintended consequence that I'm not sure how to get around.  I want 3 rotation transforms to be applied simultaneously to 1 graphics object.  Instead, I get 3 separate separate copies of the graphics object, one per transformation.

The documentation does state that this will be the outcome of using multiple transformations on a graphics object.

> GeometricTransformation[g, {t1, t2, ...}]
>   ***represents multiple copies*** of g transformed by a collection of transformations.

My question is: how is it possible to achieve the the outcome that I described instead of getting multiple copies?

Here is the code I am executing:

```
Manipulate[
  Graphics3D[{
    EdgeForm[None], 
    GeometricTransformation[Cylinder[], 
      {RotationTransform[a Pi, {1, 0, 0}], 
       RotationTransform[b Pi, {0, 1, 0}], 
       RotationTransform[c Pi, {0, 0, 1}]}]}], 
  {{a, 0}, -1, 1}, 
  {{b, 0}, -1, 1}, 
  {{c, 0}, -1, 1}, 
  SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

If anyone could show me a way to accomplish this, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`RotationTransform[a Pi, {1, 0, 0}]` is nothing more than a matrix, so you can compose/combine such functions using matrix multiplication. For example:

```
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[None], 
   GeometricTransformation[Cylinder[], 
      RotationTransform[.5 Pi, {1, 0, 0}].RotationTransform[0.2 Pi, {0, 1, 0}].RotationTransform[0.1 Pi, {0, 1, 0}]]}]
```

[image]

In the above code the dot `.` stands for matrix multiplication, which applies the various transformations in sequence.

Comment: Interesting.  Strictly speaking, a transform is a `TransformationFunction` **of** a matrix, and I had always used `TransformationMatrix` to get the matrix to work with.  The manual does not seem to include your usage of `Dot`.  Is it documented or did you just happen on it some way?

Comment: This is very insightful! Makes a lot of sense now. Thank you!

Comment: @Michael E2 You are correct in that these are `TransformationFunctions` (and not, strictly speaking, the matrices themselves). For example, `Dot` does not work in all cases: you cannot take the product of a RotationMatrix and a vector. I don't recall when I first saw this.

Answer (score 10):

Use [`Composition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Composition.html):

```
Manipulate[Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[None],
   GeometricTransformation[Cylinder[],
    Composition[
     RotationTransform[a Pi, {1, 0, 0}], 
     RotationTransform[b Pi, {0, 1, 0}], 
     RotationTransform[c Pi, {0, 1, 0}]]]}],
 {{a, 0}, -1, 1}, {{b, 0}, -1, 1}, {{c, 0}, -1, 1}, 
 SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(I'm not sure which order you want, and whether the `c` rotation is meant to be about the `y`-axis as in the OP's code.)

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks! And yeah, the `c` rotation was meant to be about the `z`-axis {0,0,1}, that was just a mistake. Of course, rotation about the `z`-axis for a cylinder does absolutely nothing because of symmetry, but I will use this transformation for a number of different objects. Thanks again.